# How to wrap text in textblock?

Tags: c#, xaml

I`m trying to get a textbox to auto fill it's text and to align it in the center of the app. I know how to align it in the center, but not how I can get the text to autofill.

For example:

I have some text in a textblock (see the code below), and the problem is that it only shows the first five words. I've been trying to set every *Text Alignment* property. So far no good.
Can anyone help me with this?

```
        <TextBlock Text="Het Commerciële Huis uit Aalten (Achterhoek) is een instituut op het gebied van optimalisatie van commercie en communicatie. Wij werken met passie aan uw resultaat" Margin="0,50,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" />
```

P.S.

It would also be nice if anyone can tell me how I can give the textbox a width equal to 50% of the client width.

With kind regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stackpanel can help to wrap textblock properly:

```
<Viewbox>
   <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="400">
       <TextBlock x:Name="subHeaderText" Text="Het Commerciële Huis uit Aalten (Achterhoek) is een instituut op het gebied van optimalisatie van commercie en communicatie. Wij werken met passie aan uw resultaat" FontSize="10" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="Black" />
   </StackPanel>
</Viewbox>
```

or just use the `TextWrapping` property of the `TextBlock` control:

```
<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">Het Commerciële Huis uit Aalten (Achterhoek) is een instituut op het gebied van optimalisatie van commercie en communicatie. Wij werken met passie aan uw resultaat</TextBlock>
```

There are many techniques to split window on two similar parts. In my view the most flexible technique dividing on two parts of the window is using `Layout` control called `Grid`:

```
<Grid>
   <!-- Define Columns -->
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>    

   <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" TextWrapping="Wrap">Het Commerciële Huis uit Aalten (Achterhoek) is een instituut op het gebied van optimalisatie van commercie en communicatie. Wij werken met passie aan uw resultaat</TextBlock>       
   <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="Second Part"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it using some grids.

*First grid defines two rows - one for header one for content

*Content grid defines three columns - one is central and is with 50% size, the other two are each 25% size

*And you have your content grid that is on the second row where you put the rest of your page's content.

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Background="Purple" x:Name="header" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="ADSADASDSADSADSADSADSA adasdsadasd asdad dsadasd sa ADSADASDSADSADSADSADSA adasdsadasd asdad dsadasd sa ADSADASDSADSADSADSADSA adasdsadasd asdad dsadasd sa"
                   Grid.Column="1"
                   Foreground="White"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                   TextAlignment="Center" 
                   TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="content" Background="Green">
        <!--Page content goes here-->
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```